# Binding golang sockets to a specific interface globally

Tags: go

I've been working with a golang application lately that does network i/o using a bunch of protocols- HTTP (TCP), DNS and WHOIS (UDP) as well as a few others. Some make use of third-party APIs

The application is open-source so I would like to make changes allowing me to specify the network interface for the sockets to bind to, allowing me to use different interfaces depending on a runtime flag. The only way around this without writing code would be to modify the system-wide routing table each time I want to utilize a different interface, which isn't a very appealing solution

Before I go an modify every instance where a `Dialer` is used (or try to create a wrapper that they can all use) is there a golang feature that would allow setting the interface globally once, so that the various `Dialer` invocations would "Just Work"- and adhere to the interface I specified?

I did some searching and have only found ways to do this when each Dialer is created (using `DialerContext.LocalAddr`) but given I'm really a C programmer and not a golang programmer, I realize I may be totally missing a golang idiom for doing something like this

Comment: The interface in Go is basically the same as in C, and has the same limitations. There is no global way to bind to an interface, you need a system specific syscall when it is possible. You can bind to a local IP, which needs to be done when you create the socket.

Comment: Kind of what I was expecting. I can have a few common Dialer wrappers but I’ll have to do a bunch of one-off changes as there are some third-party module APIs doing networking also. If golang used libc this would have been an easy solve using LD_PRELOAD :/